# Error invoking method-Failed to launch JVM when Trying to Deploy Javafx App

Tags: java, javafx

I built a simple program with javafx and have got to the part of deploying the app for use outside of intelliJ(community edition). I cant seem to figure out why the method isnt being invoked when i try launching the exe outside of the IDE.It shows two alert boxes, the first says Error invoking method, the second afterwards says Failed to launch JVM after I try and open the exe from explorer.

```
    package sample;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome");
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);


         primaryStage.show();
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            grid.setHgap(10);
            grid.setVgap(10);
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
            //Adding text labels and text fields
            Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome");
            sceneTitle.setId("welcome-text");
            grid.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0,2, 1);
            TextField userTextField = new TextField();
            grid.add(userTextField, 1,1);
            Label userName = new Label("User Name: ");
            grid.add(userName, 0 ,1);
            Label pw = new Label("Password: ");
            grid.add(pw, 0,2);
            PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
            grid.add(pwBox,1,2);
            //grid lines for debugging
            grid.setGridLinesVisible(false);
            //grid lines for debugging
            Button btn = new Button("Sign In");
            HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
            hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
            grid.add(hbBtn, 1,4);
            final Text actionTarget = new Text();
            grid.add(actionTarget,1,6);
            btn.setOnAction(e -> {actionTarget.setText("Sign In button 
Pressed");});
        actionTarget.setId("actiontarget");
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //Initialize sytlesheets variable
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is my controller class (lol)

```
    package sample;

    public class Controller {
    }
```

and finally... my fxml

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

the last thing i have to help out is this here but im not sure how to read it to get to the base of the issue...

```
C:\Users\Joop\IdeaProjects\Hello\out\artifacts\JavaFXApp\bundles>java -jar "JavaFXApp.jar"
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:64)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: You'll probably benefit from reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384

Comment: +1 for a "basic", but well structured and presented question, with full stack trace and relevant code. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

> im not sure how to read it to get to the base of the issue...

The key part is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:64)
```

That shows you that Main.java, line 64 threw a `NullPointerException`. So the exception is thrown because of the following line:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
```

Specifically, it's most likely that `Main.class.getResource("Login.css")` is returning null. This will be because it can't find the `Login.css`, almost certainly because you haven't included it in your build (hence why you can't run it successfully outside the IDE.)

Comment: Thank you. I gathered that was the exact issue when I tried to run it. Thank you for everything. Even with such a "basic' issue, you've definitely helped me on my journey with this insight.